# Is it possible to create a Mongoose hook to apply a projection to all queries

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, hook

I'd like to prevent a user's encrypted password from getting sent over the wire each time a user requests their information. I know that in mongo I can apply a projection to achieve this

```
db.users.findByID(_id, { password: 0 } )
```

but I would prefer to have some sort of `.pre()` hook to that will apply it to every query. Is this or a functional equivalent possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can configure a field so it'll be excluded from queries by default using `select`:

```
let UserSchema = new Schema({
  ...
  password : { type : String, select : false },
  ...
});
```

You can override that on a per-query basis if you do require the field to be returned:

```
db.users.findByID(_id, { password: 1 } )
```

Documented here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-select